# Mostrar la orden del usuario en la sección de pedidos de woocommerce después de haber iniciado sesión

Tags: wordpress, login, woocommerce

Estoy usando un pugin llamado: "WooCoommerce Request a Quote".

Quiero mostrar la orden de un usuario en su cuenta que creó previamente, es decir, aquí:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy mapeando los datos del formulario de contact form 7 y llegan correctamente en la sección de pedidos de WooCommerce. 
¿Habrá alguna forma de mostrarle esos pedidos al usuario?

Este es el pedido del cliente que contact form 7 se lleva correctamente:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>
<div class="woocommerce-page">
    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>

        <?php
            //loop through the list
            foreach ( $data_arr as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            ?>
                    <tr id="<?php echo $cart_item['row_id']?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $qlist[$cart_item_key], $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">
                    <?php
                    foreach($arr_cols as $colname => $coltitle) { ?>
                        <td class="product-<?php echo $colname;?>" data-title="<?php echo $coltitle;?>"><?php echo $cart_item[$colname]; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
            <?php
            }//end of loop
            //add or display rows
            do_action('dvin_wcql_diplay_rows',$arr_cols,$cols_counter,$grand_total_qty,$grand_total_price,$data_arr);
    ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

pero, ¿por que no aparecen en los pedidos del cliente?

Answer (score 0):

Dejé de usar el contact form 7 para este preyecto y utilizé el que trae por default el plugin (que ese sí agrega los pedidos en la cuenta del usuario).

Solo tuve que crear otra plantilla personalizada para crear mi propio formulario siguiendo la documentación del plugin

https://www.burocreativo.com/namm/wp-content/plugins/Request%20a%20Quote/documentation/

De ésta manera pude resolver el problema que tenía